# The toggle change does not detect me

Tags: html, angular, typescript, nebular

I have a toggle that activates or deactivates a tooltip in a table. At the moment, it is activated when starting the application but I want it to be deactivated when starting the application and it is only activated when the toggle is set to true. I have the code as I show it below. I use the Nebular library for angular v9

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
           if (
          changes.showTooltip &&
          changes.showTooltip.currentValue !== changes.showTooltip.previousValue
        ) {
          this.cdr.detectChanges();
        }
      }

    toggleTooltip() {
        this.showTooltipFlag = !this.showTooltipFlag;
        console.log(this.showTooltipFlag);

        if (this.showTooltipFlag) {
          this._render.removeClass(this._document.body, "hide-tooltip");
        } else {
          this._render.addClass(this._document.body, "hide-tooltip");
        }
      }
  
<condor-table
          *ngIf="!isLoading"
          [tableTemplates]="templates | async"
          [columnsDefinition]="tableDef"
          (rowInfo)="rowClicked($event)"
          [dataCondor]="messages$ | async"
          [showTooltip]="true"
        ></condor-table>

    <div class="search__toggle">
          <span>{{
            (showTooltipFlag ? "hide_tooltip" : "show_tooltip") | translate
          }}</span>
          <nb-toggle
            [checked]="showTooltipFlag"
            (checkedChange)="toggleTooltip()"
          ></nb-toggle>
        </div>
```

Comment: welcome to the site. Please do not post code as an image.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing it:

you can change in your ngOnInIt:

```
this.showTooltipFlag=false
```

or else you can also try this way,
while declaring showTooltipFlag:

```
showTooltipFlag: boolean=false
```

Comment: I have the variable declared to false and what it does is start the app with the toggle turned off but it keeps showing me the tooltip when I hover over the table, what I want is that both the toggle and when hovering over the table, the tooltip is turned off . I've tried both ways you told me and it still doesn't work for me.